# Visual Studio 2015 - "Unable to step. The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When debugging I get the following error:

> Unable to step. The operation could not be completed. A retry should
>   be performed

After clicking OK, the dialog returns:

> The debugger cannot continue running the process. The operation could
>   not be completed. A retry should be performed.

The solution is set to "Debug" and "Any CPU". After restarting the application I can step through the code but it takes 5-10 seconds to step on something that normally goes instant. However CPU, RAM and HDD is operating normally and not peaking. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Is your programming hooking into anything in Windows itself? Like creating keyboard hooks, window subclassing hooks, etc.?

Comment: The application is talking with a https://www.rabbitmq.com/ server that runs locally but otherwise no. It is a simple console application that reads email using imap. @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by completely uninstalling Visual Studio and ReSharper. I used this tool:

https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

After re-install everything worked again.

Comment: This did not help me, I still have the problem. Sadly. I'm Debugging a Console App, that consume some WCF Service.

Answer (score 10):

I've also ran into this issue before in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on Windows 7 SP1 (64-bit).

Try disabling the Visual Studio hosting process.
Project Properties > Debug > uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"

Also, are you running out of memory?

Are you debugging an ASP.NET website?

> A known issue with the Visual Studio debugger causing this problem.
>   There is a race condition that happens when all of the following are
>   true:
>
> 1. Script debugging is enabled in IE
> 2. User is debugging IE and another process
> 3. The other process stops (hits breakpoint, step operation completes, stops at an exception, etc) at a moment when IE is not running script
>      code
> 4. IE starts running script code at roughly the same moment that the user hits F10/F5 in Visual Studio. The most likely reason for this to
>      happen is that the code from ‘setTimeout’ is run – there could be
>      other reasons as well.
>
> Workaround
>
> 1. If you hit this problem, you can try detaching and reattaching the debugger.
>
>    -or-
> 2. This problem happens when debugging ASP.NET and when script debugging is enabled in IE. If you disable script debugging in IE, or
>      toggle it on and off when switching between debugger server-side and
>      client-side problems, you would be able to work around the issue.
>
>    -or-
> 3. If your web application is using setTimeout, you may be able to avoid or at least reduce the problem by doing something to ensure that
>      script runs less often. This could mean increasing the timeout value,
>      or this could mean adding conditions around when setTimeout is used.

Sources:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2008/06/07/getting-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-a-retry-should-be-performed-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/
- https://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/getting-quot-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-a-retry-should-be-performed-quot-while-debugging-in-visual-studio
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2320a943-d52d-437a-abec-6f1e9f929b52/debugger-error-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed?forum=vsdebug

Are you debugging a Universal Windows App?

If so, a work-around could be to reinstall "Tools for Universal Windows Appps Development" as follows:

> ·         If the “Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development” are
>   still installed:
>
> 1. Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2105, click Change.
> 2. In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
> 3. Deselect the feature “Tools for Universal Windows App Development”
> 4. Select “Tools for Universal Windows App Development” again, and click Update.
>
> ·         If you have already uninstalled the “Tools for Universal
>   Windows Apps Development”:
>
> ·         Reinstall “Tools for Universal Windows App Development”
>
> ·         Or, take the following steps to reinstall the JavaScript
>   project system and language service:
>
> §  Download the installer for your edition of Visual Studio, e.g.,
>   vs_community.exe.
>
> §  Open a CMD window, and run the following command: vs_community.exe
>   /modify /installselectableitems JavaScript_Hidden /passive

Source:
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9936d80-087d-4cad-93bf-ca4873889773/the-debugger-cannot-continue-running-the-process?forum=vsdebug

Comment: fyi, Just started getting this error while debugging a WCF site in Chrome.  Under the Advanced tab, the options "disable script debugging" IE & other, are both checked.

Comment: @crokusek, try disabling the Visual Studio hosting process. See the top of my updated answer.

Comment: This did not help me, I still have the problem. Sadly. I'm Debugging a Console App, that consume some WCF Service

Answer (score 6):

In **Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019** you can do that:

Go to **Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General**

Turn off

> "Break all processes when one process breaks"

Answer (score 1):

In my case detaching from the process and attaching again solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem but I had a single class library project in a solution so I just rebuild the solution and then it worked.