# VS Debugger - "The debugger cannot continue running the process. The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

We are running VS2015 and debugging a asp.Net web application with multiple start up items. The debugger will not show this error for some time and then occasionally for no reason display.

The error message: "The debugger cannot continue running the process. The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed."

[image]

This displays when the debugger isn't stepping or when we try to step or click 'Continue'. Can someone enlighten me to why this would be displaying and what I can do to stop this in the future? TIA

Comment: Have you select start up project which can not be started? If possible, please check if those threads can give you some helps:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363928/the-debugger-cannot-continue-running-the-process-unable-to-start-debugger/17344809#17344809 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019321/visual-studio-2015-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-a-re

Comment: Yeah our solution has over 250 projects so I only start a handful when debugging - this isn't the problem because it will run fine for some time and then on a rerun maybe the debugger will kill randomly. We haven't changed any settings/code between these debug runs either

Comment: @DanielLoudon, As you said that you get this issue during you set multiple start up items, if so, do you mean that it works well if you just set one specific project and .aspx as the start up project/item? Like this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2017, if you debug several projects at the same time, try to reduce the project number, view the result.